# Background job for ASP.NET application

Tags: .net, asp.net, background-process

My team is developing an ASP.NET application, which among other things contains an import functionality. The import will typically be initiated by a user entering some settings in a web page, including the local file to be imported. When the user hits the "import" the file should be uploaded and then imported.

The import can be quite a lengthy operation, so it is not possible to do it directly from the aspx.cs code, it need to be done in some background way. Also it is important that once the file is uploaded, the import is not lost. I would also like the import to start *immediately*, not having to wait for a service or scheduled task that just checks for available work every X minutes.

What I've found as alternatives so far is:

- Background thread from ThreadPool or similar in ASP.NET. Will mostly work, but if the app pool is recycled the work is lost.
- Service with a timer that regularly checks a work table in the DB and runs the import. Will work, but either has the delay or causes very frequent requests for work from the DB.
- Service with a change notification query (don't know the exact name, but it is possible to subscribe to changes from SQL server).
- Service getting work items through MSMQ.
- WCF service, hosted within a system service and not within ASP.NET to avoid recycling. Either the WCF service is called internally from ASP.NET or it is directly exposed and called from the client through AJAX (if a non-IIS-hosted WCF can expose AJAX endpoints).

Are there any other alternatives? Is there anyone with experience of the above alternatives?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could have a windows service, which watches the upload directory for changes (e.g. using [FileSystemWatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx)).

That way, there would be no (or only minimal) delay until the service starts working and you don't need any kind of polling from the service.

As for the settings (entered by the user): either store them in a DB (and query them from the service) or write them to a file as well.

Answer (score 0):

as you mentioned there are different approaches and alternatives.

we have successfully used a Windows Service working as an Agent ( job Manager ) and created classes of kind Worker which are plugged in and configured with a small ASPX page without need to touch the agent at all when a new worker is added.

In this way the agent is always up an running as windows service and depending on the kind of worker and its configuration it calls the execute method of the worker and the job is carried out.

you can also have a much simpler design like you said with MSMQ, we also used and works fine.

Answer (score 0):

This is similar to emailing reports to users on request we were doing.

1. Users request reports through a Web App which adds records to Queue table.
2. Windows Service monitors Queue table and generates reports (which can take seconds to over an hour based on report type) as PDFs.
3. Another Windows Service emails the reports out once they are prepared.

Both #2 and #3 check DB periodically (each for relevant "Status" of queued item) and process all queued but not processed items as batch - not one at a time.

Answer (score 0):

A DB trigger that calls a CLR stored procedure that does the actual work?

I have good experience of MSMQ though, just don't overload MSMQ with too much data. Post import-id:s or similiar to MSMQ and store the actual payload in a database table.
MSMQ can handle quite a bit of data, but most management tools get awfully slow as they tend to peek at all messages (including payload) in the queue on startup.